# How to open Virtual Box on Windows 10

Tags: ssh, vagrant, windows-10, putty

I am unable to access the virtual box that I initialized with the "vagrant up" command. I now get this:

```
[C:\web\Homestead]vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state   directory
------------------------------------------------------------------------
13650ef  default virtualbox running C:/web/Homestead

The above shows information about all known Vagrant environments
on this machine. This data is cached and may not be completely
up-to-date. To interact with any of the machines, you can go to
that directory and run Vagrant, or you can use the ID directly
with Vagrant commands from any directory. For example:
"vagrant destroy 1a2b3c4d"

[C:\web\Homestead]vagrant ssh 13650ef
C:/web/Homestead/Vagrantfile:4: warning: already initialized constant 
....
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

The executable 'cygpath' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

I am running Windows 10 and set my environment variables, as follows:

```
Path c:\php;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\cygwin64;
C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

The cygpath file it seeks is clearly under both c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin and under C:\cygwin64.

I tried to access the virtual box through Putty, but got the simple message "connection refused". I have used Puttygen to convert the ssh keys to Putty ppk files.

I have tried to retrace my steps initializing the virtual box, but I fail to see how to step forward and open the box.

Should I destroy my virtual box and start over?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the PATH paths with 'Program Files' to Progra~1 paths or to wrap each path item with double-quotes, e.g.:

> Path c:\php;"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"; "C:\Program
>   Files\Git\usr\bin";C:\cygwin64; C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm

or

> Path c:\php;C:\Progra~1\Oracle\VirtualBox;
>   C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin;C:\cygwin64;
>   C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: yorammi - didn't solve the prob. :(  Now I can't even use vagrant up command. I don't know what happened. Something changed when I tried to configure Putty, but I don't know what.